# Running two tensorflow graphs in parallel, one producing data and one consuming data

Tags: c++, multithreading, tensorflow

I have one tensorflow graph which produces output and another graph which consumes the output produced by the first. I managed to get a working version using a Python queue by running the graphs in two separate threads and using the queue to feed data from the first graph to the second. If no data is available, the queue blocks the "consumer" thread until more data comes in. The end goal is to export both graphs into C++ and implement the same producer-consumer relationship. Is there a way to use tensorflow's built-in FIFOQueue in C++ to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Found a solution. Created a global session and just ran the two operations in separate threads, sharing the same FIFOqueue. Since dequeue operations are blocking, the consumer must wait for the producer to fill the queue if the queue is empty. Similarly, the producer won't produce more until space is available in the queue.

Comment: You should put your own comment into an answer and mark it as accepted.